# ExecuteScalar returns different result than Pure SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-4.0, ado.net

I am running into a very interesting bug (or feature).

I have a ADO Command object that makes a call to the database.

The call looks similar to:

```
cmd.CommandText = "uspMySearch";
cmd.CommmandType = Command.StoredProcedure.
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchBy", searchBy)
// The value of searchBy is: '( FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, steve''s) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, game) )'

int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

// The result returned is 0.  I was expecting 1.
```

When I execute the same query in SQL/Query Analyzer, I get a different result.

The sql looks like this:

```
EXEC uspMySearch @SearchBy = '( FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, steve''s) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, game) )'

// The result returned is 1.  This is the expected result.
```

In order to confirm I was calling the correct stored procedure, I modifed uspMySearch to return a random number.  I was calling the right Sp!

Anyone have any insights as to whats going on here?

Thanks.

Steve

Environment

SQL/Server 2008 R2

.NET 4.0

Comment: Jump into SQL profiler and watch what the query looks like that is being sent to SQL Server.

Comment: What does your stored proc look like?  It looks like you're dynamically generating and executing SQL, is that right?

Comment: Are you returning `SELECT 1/0` from the procedure? Or are you just doing a `RETURN 1/0`? You wont get a value from the `RETURN` method.

Comment: maybe you should add order clause to your sp?

Comment: When I got this abnormal behavior, the first thing I did was run SQL Profiler.  It did not reveal anything out of the normal. My stored procedure takes SearchBy as a parameter and then run Select Count(*) from MyTable WHERE CONTAINS (*, @SearchBy).  Nothing magical.  I think the problem has to do with the single quote.  I had to ESCAPE the quote, that is why you see ''.  Finally, the value I am returning is from the result set, not a Return Value.

Comment: Problem solved.  When I used SQL/Profiler, I noticed that my statement had multiple quotes, i.e., steve''''s.  At first, I thought SQL/Profiler may have added them.  Then I recall the SP was modified several days (or longer) ago.  SQL/Server was using the Cached version of the SP.  I ran sp_recompile and now everything is working fine.  The clue was the four quotes in Profiler.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've got an extraneous single quote in your `searchBy` variable in the C#, try:

```
// note steve's rather than steve''s, shouldn't need to escape the single quote
string searchBy =
    "( FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, steve's) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, game) )";
...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchBy", searchBy);

int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

---

Another possibility, raised by @FlyingStreudel in a comment, is that your stored procedure is not using `SELECT` to return the value. If you're using `RETURN`, you should instead try:

```
var retval = new SqlParameter("@RETVAL", SqlDbType.Int);
retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add(retval);
...
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

int result = Convert.ToInt32(retval.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteScalar` is not for executing `Stored Procedures` - for that you you use `ExecuteNonQuery` combined with `Parameters` with direction `Output` / `InputOutput` / `Return`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.parameterdirection.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx

**EDIT** - perhaps the following works too (although wouldn't recommend it):

```
cmd.CommandText = "uspMySearch";
cmd.CommmandType = Command.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchBy", searchBy).Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;


int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

var Result = cmd.Parameters ["@SearchBy"].Value;
```

Comment: Really?  The Microsoft websites example of how to return a single value from an SP uses ExecuteScalar - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37hwc7kt(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: thanks... learned something new... from my experience this doesn't always work as expected - I guess it depends on the Stored Procedure...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to throw out a wild guess, but I'm guessing it has something to do with your cast.  Can you change the code to:

```
object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

And use the debugger to inspect the `result` variable to see what it is (and what it's type is).  This may give you (or me) a clue as to what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

When you say the result returned is 1 - how is it returned; resultset or printed out?

Normally when using ExecuteScalar() I use a query which selects a single column value (i.e. of the format SELECT ... FROM ...).